# In my first commit I am unable to push the changes as i already have .gitignore and README.md in my github,diff from local

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-merge-conflict

I am very new to git and I am self learning it.

I have created a repository in github which has these two files .gitignore and README.md. **only**.

Now I have an angular project in a folder in my local.

I want to push my project to the newly created github repository,
so i used the following commands in order--

- rd .git /S/Q
- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "First commit"
- git remote add origin
  https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/test-git-commands.git
- git push -u origin master

after this I am getting the following error---

```
To https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/test-git-commands.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/test-git-commands.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I understood that the .gitignore and README.md files that are present in my github repo is diff from what i have in local , so i have to pull the changes first and then merge it and then i can push it.
But I tried doing that--
I executed the following commands in order, started from the very begining as i do not know how to proceed after getting the error, so I thought I will pull an dmerge the changes before pushing it.

- rd .git /S/Q
- git init
- git remote add origin
  https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/test-git-commands.git
- git pull origin master

Then I got the following message. I do not know how to proceed after this-

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .gitignore
        README.md
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I searched in Google I got this answer--

```
The problem is that you are not tracking the files 
locally but identical files are tracked remotely so
 in order to "pull" your system would be forced to 
overwrite the local files which are not version controlled.

Try running

git add * 
git stash
git pull
```

But here the local files are getting overwritten , I do not want this. I want my local changes to be pushed. How to resolve the merge conflict here to preserve my local changes.

Through Vs code git GUI i was able to merge my local changes, but i want to do it through cmd.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this----

After getting that error while pulling from origin(i.e, my github repo url)

I went to my local folder manually edited and kept only the local changes--
i.e,

```
between <<<<<<<<<<<<<HEAD and =========
```

then i ran the following commands--

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "Resolved merge conflicts"
3. git push origin master

It worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you don't want to keep the files on you remote repository you can use `git push -f`

`-f` means force and it will overwrite your remote repository (so use it carefully)

Option two is to cancel your commit with `git reset HEAD^` (it will reset your commit but not the files you modified, like if you were before `git commit`), then stash your changes with `git stash`. You can now `git pull` and then unstash with `git stash pop`, handle the conflicts then commit and push.

Finally the easiest way would have been not to create those files on Github and do exactly what you have done, then you wouldn't have any conflict.

Comment: yes definitely it would have been easy if i had not created the files in the first place, but I wanted to learn!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to clone the repository afresh in a new folder, carry across the changes you require in the two files, and then commit and push the result.

```
git clone https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/test-git-commands.git FOLDER
# Make appropriate changes
git add FILES
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push
```

To get the stash approach to work you would need to make sure the untracked files get stashed before the pull (potentially force adding them with `git add -f`), and remember to apply/pop the stash afterwards to 'unstash' those changes.

Comment: # Make appropriate changes--- How do I make the appropriate changes--? Going to my local folder and manually make the changes? Is there any other way?

Comment: I can't give you exact steps because I can't reconstruct your exact git/local working directory state from the information I have, but the non-manual way of dealing with it is with the stash approach, where the aim is to stash away all changes you've made, pull from the repository, then unstash those changes (causing a merge), then pushing the result. A general approach to doing that would be to `git add` all your local changes (use `-f` if required to overcome gitignore), `git stash`, `git pull`, `git stash pop`, resolve any conflicts if they exist, then commit and push the result.